# Express is not reading the request body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new in node and express. So, I was learning how to do post request. When I learned, it was alright and it was creating another document in mangodb database. Today when I tried to do the same, this problem occurred.

[image]

I tried different things like removing required part in schema. But it seems express is failing to read req.body since when I send the request without any required fields in schema, it happily accepted and filled up default fields. I don't really understand what is happening. I was parallelly doing another project which is not giving this error.

PS. I am using mongoose@5.

Code to create tour:

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        tour: newTour,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you saying that `req.body` in your code here is empty or `undefined`?  If so, then that's probably because you don't have the right Express middleware to read the body for that type of content-type or you aren't sending the right type of content-type.

Comment: Are you using `body-paeser` for parse request data?!

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, it seems req.body is undefined.

Comment: @Pooya no, I am not.

Comment: What is the content-type from your POST?  If it's JSON, then you need `app.use(express.json())` as middleware before your POST request handler.  That will read the JSON body of the request, parse it and put it in `req.body`.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks a lot, it worked. Somehow I deleted that line and this was happening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the `content-type` for your POST is `application/json`, then you need this:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

as middleware before your POST request handler. That will read the JSON body of the request, parse it and put it in `req.body`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure app.use(express.json()) is at the top of all your middlewares

```js
// middleware 
app.use(express.json()) //Add it first then others follw

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```